# swagger combine some repeating annotations

Tags: spring, swagger

I use `.useDefaultResponseMessages(false)` and in each method

```
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success", response = Order.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Forbidden"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Failure")})
public Order getOrder......

@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success", response = User.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Forbidden"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Failure")})
public User getUser......
```

Can I combine some repeating annotations?(default)

Answer (score 5):

### 1. Use `@ApiResponses` at controller level.

Define common responses at the controller level instead of repeating them for each method:

```
@ApiResponses({
        @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Forbidden"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Failure")})
@Controller
public class UserOrderController {
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success", response = Order.class)
    @GetMapping("/order")
    public Order getOrder() { /*......*/ }

    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success", response = User.class)
    @GetMapping("/user")
    public User getUser() { /*......*/ }
}
```

And actually, it's not required to specify `response` type in `@ApiResponse` if it matches method return type. So, in the provided example, we can define all responses once per controller in order to reduce repeating annotations.

### 2. Use custom annotations

Share the repeating annotations between controllers by defining a custom annotation:

```
/**
 * A convenient meta-annotation for Swagger API responses.
 */
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@ApiResponses({
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Forbidden"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Failure")})
@interface DefaultApiResponses {}
```

Then use it like this:

```
@DefaultApiResponses
@Controller
public class UserOrderController {
    @GetMapping("/order")
    public Order getOrder() { /*......*/ }

    @GetMapping("/user")
    public User getUser() { /*......*/ }
}
```

The source code presented in this answer is available over on [Github](https://git.io/fpmRK).

Comment: What if you want to add new annotation which is not from default set? is there a best way we could accommodate in the same annotation? As far as I have tried we have to specify @ApiResponses(...) again

Comment: @DeepakShinde yes, you are right. we can override `@ApiResponses` definition at method-level, and we have to specify defaults again if we do so.