# Is it possible to have a "reference" to an annotation instance to reduce code duplication?

Tags: java, annotations

I'm using swagger annotations to document an api, and they're quite verbose.  I find myself repeating certain annotations verbatim.  like:

```java
public Response myAPI(
        @Parameter(
                description = "Some long long description",
                required = true,
                schema = @Schema(allowableValues = {"abc", "def", "hij"}, defaultValue = "abc"))
        @QueryParam("foo") String foo) {
}
```

What I'd love to have is:

```java
static Parameter myRepeatingParam = @Parameter(
              description = "Some long long description",
              required = true,
              schema = @Schema(allowableValues = {"abc", "def", "hij"}, 
              defaultValue = "abc"));

public Response myAPI01(
        @myRepeatingParam
        @QueryParam("foo") String foo) {
}

public Response myAPI02(
        @myRepeatingParam
        @QueryParam("foo") String foo) {
}
```

**Update**

Using the meta-annotations works some places, but not others.  For instance, given:

```java
@Target({PARAMETER, METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Parameter(in = ParameterIn.QUERY, name = "foo")
public @interface TestSwagger {
}
```

This compiles:

```java
    public Response myAPI(
            @TestSwagger
            @QueryParam("foo") String foo) {
        return null;
    }
```

But in this use case it does not, because `@TestSwagger` isn't a `@Parameter` and there appears to be no polymorphism in this case.

```java
    @Operation(
            parameters = { // array of @Parameters
                    @TestSwagger,
                    @Parameter(in = ParameterIn.QUERY, name = "bar")},
            )
    public Response myAPINope(
            @QueryParam("foo") String foo,
            @QueryParam("bar") String bar) {
        return null;
    }
```

This 2nd case is more what I'm going after and doesn't seem possible.

Comment: Not natively, but it's doable at the framework level, like Jackson does: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401581/how-to-create-an-annotation-that-is-a-group-of-jackson-annotations

Comment: Does this answer your question? [swagger combine some repeating annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46324478/swagger-combine-some-repeating-annotations)

Comment: @M.Prokhorov - the "meta" annotation answer looked promising, but it doesn't actually compile for annotations nested inside other annotations, which is my actual use case.  (params are inside of `ApiResponse`

Comment: At least Java allows you to extract primitives, strings, and arrays of both to static finals.

Comment: @marathon, what do you mean "doesn't compile"? If you meant code from your original snippet and that doesn't compile - it's the correct compiler behavior, you can't assign annotation to a variable - you have to define a proper `@interface`. Otherwise, please show your actual code and what doesn't compile.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov - no, not my code snippet from the question.  See the update at the bottom of my question.